# How to solve app get crashed

Tags: android

Am developing an GPS Tracking application. When i press the the login button it has to show latitude longitude and accuracy. its not working correctly, app getting crashed.Please help me to solve this problem. Thanks in advance.

here is my activity.class:

```
btnShowLocation = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnShowLocation);
        // show location button click event
        btnShowLocation.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


                AndroidGPSTrackingActivity.this.startService(new Intent(AndroidGPSTrackingActivity.this, GPSTracker.class));
                // create class object
                 // MyTimerTask myTask = new MyTimerTask();
                 Context c = getApplicationContext();
                  SharedPreferences app_preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(c);
                @SuppressWarnings("unused")
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = app_preferences.edit();
                    TimerTask scanTask;
                    final Handler handler = new Handler();
                    Timer t = new Timer();
                    scanTask = new TimerTask() {
                        GPSTracker gps;
                        List<Double> l = new ArrayList<Double>();
                        TreeMap<Double,List<Double>> list = new  TreeMap<Double,List<Double>>();
                             public void run() {
                                    handler.post(new Runnable() {
                                           // @SuppressLint("UseValueOf")
                                            @SuppressLint("UseValueOf")
                                            public void run() {
                                                  Context c = getApplicationContext();
                                                  SharedPreferences app_preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(c);
                                                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = app_preferences.edit();
                                                int counter = app_preferences.getInt("counter", 0);
                                              Log.i("log", "maaaap"+list);
                                                Double latitude=new Double(0.0d);
                                                Double longitude=new Double(0.0d);
                                                    l = new ArrayList<Double>();
                                                    gps = new GPSTracker(AndroidGPSTrackingActivity.this);
                                                    // check if GPS enabled     
                                                    if(gps.canGetLocation()){

                                                         l.add(gps.getLatitude());
                                                         l.add(gps.getLongitude());
                                                         list.put(gps.getAccur(),l);
                                                         Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your Location is - \nLat: " + gps.getLatitude() + "\nLong:" + gps.getLongitude()+ "\nAccracy:"+gps.getAccur(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                                                         Log.i("log", "latitude"+gps.getLatitude());
                                                         Log.i("log", "longitude"+gps.getLongitude());
                                                         Log.i("log", "gps.getAccur()"+gps.getAccur());
                                                         Log.d("tag", "Finding Latitude");
                                                         latitude = gps.getLatitude();
                                                        Log.d("tag", "Lat: "+String.valueOf(latitude));
                                                        Log.d("tag", "Finding Longitude");
                                                        longitude  = gps.getLongitude();
                                                        Log.d("tag", "Lon: "+String.valueOf(longitude));
                                                        String Text =
                                                        "\nLat: " + gps.getLatitude() +
                                                        "\nLan:" + gps.getLongitude()+"\nAcrcy="+gps.getAccur();
                                                       //txtData.setText(Text);


                                                        sendSMS(readfromFilesms(), Text);

                                                    }

                                                if(counter<12)
                                                  {
                                                    if(gps.getAccur()<=3.0D)
                                                    {
                                                        Double  d =  (Double)list.firstKey();
                                                        Log.i("log", "gps.firstKey()"+d);
                                                        @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
                                                        List l1 = (List)list.get(d);
                                                        Log.i("log", "gps.l1()"+(Double)l1.get(0));
                                                        Log.i("log", "gps.l2"+(Double)l1.get(1));
                                                        latitude = (Double)l1.get(0);
                                                        longitude = (Double)l1.get(1);
                                                       // String[] s = {"manjugowda.manju2@gmail.com"};
                                                        //SendMail(s,latitude.toString(),longitude.toString(),"22");
                                                        editor.putInt("counter", 0);
                                                        editor.commit(); // Very important
                                                        finish();
                                                        //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your Location is - \nLong: "+d , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                                    }
                                                    else
                                                    {
                                                        counter = app_preferences.getInt("counter", 0);
                                                        Log.i("log", "counter"+counter);
                                                        editor.putInt("counter", ++counter);
                                                        editor.commit();
                                                        finish();// Very important
                                                    }

                                                  }
                                                else
                                                {
                                                    Double  d =  (Double)list.firstKey();
                                                    Log.i("log", "gps.firstKey()"+d);
                                                    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
                                                    List l1 = (List)list.get(d);
                                                    Log.i("log", "gps.l1()"+(Double)l1.get(0));
                                                    Log.i("log", "gps.l2"+(Double)l1.get(1));
                                                    latitude = (Double)l1.get(0);
                                                    longitude = (Double)l1.get(1);
                                                    //@SuppressWarnings("unused")
                                                    //String[] s = {"manjugowda.manju2@gmail.com"};
                                                   // SendMail(s,latitude.toString(),longitude.toString(),"22");
                                                    editor.putInt("counter", 0);
                                                    editor.commit(); // Very important
                                                    finish();
                                                    //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your Accurecy is - \n: "+d , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                                }
                                            }
                                   });
                            }};
                        t.schedule(scanTask,1000,90000000);  
                        finish();
        }
        });
```

logcat error:

```
04-08 18:27:01.438: E/ActivityThread(23915):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
04-08 18:27:01.438: E/ActivityThread(23915):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
04-08 18:27:01.438: E/ActivityThread(23915):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
04-08 18:27:01.438: E/ActivityThread(23915):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-08 18:27:01.904: I/log(23915): maaaap{}
04-08 18:27:01.925: D/GPS Enabled(23915): GPS Enabled
04-08 18:27:01.925: I/System.out(23915): inside location manager
04-08 18:27:01.929: D/AndroidRuntime(23915): Shutting down VM
04-08 18:27:01.929: W/dalvikvm(23915): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x416c8d40)
04-08 18:27:01.948: E/AndroidRuntime(23915): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-08 18:27:01.948: E/AndroidRuntime(23915): Process: com.example.gpstracking, PID: 23915
04-08 18:27:01.948: E/AndroidRuntime(23915): java.lang.NullPointerException
04-08 18:27:01.948: E/AndroidRuntime(23915):    at com.example.gpstracking.AndroidGPSTrackingActivity$1$1$1.run(AndroidGPSTrackingActivity.java:163)
04-08 18:27:01.948: E/AndroidRuntime(23915):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
04-08 18:27:01.948: E/AndroidRuntime(23915):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
04-08 18:27:01.948: E/AndroidRuntime(23915):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
04-08 18:27:01.948: E/AndroidRuntime(23915):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5102)
04-08 18:27:01.948: E/AndroidRuntime(23915):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-08 18:27:01.948: E/AndroidRuntime(23915):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
04-08 18:27:01.948: E/AndroidRuntime(23915):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
04-08 18:27:01.948: E/AndroidRuntime(23915):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
04-08 18:27:01.948: E/AndroidRuntime(23915):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-08 18:27:03.605: I/Process(23915): Sending signal. PID: 23915 SIG: 9
```

GPSTracker.class:

```
public class GPSTracker extends Service implements LocationListener {

    private final Context mContext;

    // flag for GPS status
    boolean isGPSEnabled = false;

    // flag for network status
    boolean isNetworkEnabled = false;

    // flag for GPS status
    boolean canGetLocation = false;

    Location location; // location
    double latitude; // latitude
    double longitude; // longitude
    Double accur;

    public Double getAccur() {
        return accur;
    }

    public void setAccur(Double accur) {
        this.accur = accur;
    }

    // The minimum distance to change Updates in meters
    private static final long MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES = 12; // 10 meters

    // The minimum time between updates in milliseconds
    private static final long MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES = 0; // 1 sec

    // Declaring a Location Manager
    protected LocationManager locationManager;

    public Object getAccuracy;

    public GPSTracker(Context context) {
        this.mContext = context;
        getLocation();
    }

    public Location getLocation() {
        try {
            locationManager = (LocationManager) mContext
                    .getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

            // getting GPS status
            isGPSEnabled = locationManager
                    .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

            // getting network status
            /*isNetworkEnabled = locationManager
                    .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

            /*if (!isGPSEnabled && !isNetworkEnabled) {
                // no network provider is enabled
            } else {
                /*this.canGetLocation = true;
                if(isNetworkEnabled){
                    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES, MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                    Log.d("Network","Network");
                    if(locationManager!=null){
                        location=locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
                        if(location!=null){
                            System.out.println("inside location");
                            latitude = location.getLatitude();

                            System.out.println("lat"+latitude);
                            longitude = location.getLongitude();
                        }
                    }
                }*/
                if (isGPSEnabled) {
                    if (location == null) {

                        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                                LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                                MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                                MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                        Log.d("GPS Enabled","GPS Enabled");

                        if (locationManager != null) {

                            System.out.println("inside location manager");
                            location = locationManager
                                    .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                            if (location != null) {

                                System.out.println("inside location");
                                latitude = location.getLatitude();

                                System.out.println("lat"+latitude);
                                longitude = location.getLongitude();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

            if(location!=null)
            {
                setAccur(new Double(location.getAccuracy()));
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return location;
    }

    /**
     * Stop using GPS listener
     * Calling this function will stop using GPS in your app
     * */
    /*public void stopUsingGPS(){
        if(locationManager != null){
            locationManager.removeUpdates(GPSTracker.this);
        }       
    }*/

    /**
     * Function to get latitude
     * */
    public double getLatitude(){
        if(location != null){
            latitude = location.getLatitude();
        }

        // return latitude
        return latitude;
    }

    /**
     * Function to get longitude
     * */
    public double getLongitude(){
        if(location != null){
            longitude = location.getLongitude();
        }

        // return longitude
        return longitude;
    }

    /**
     * Function to check GPS/wifi enabled
     * @return boolean
     * */
    public boolean canGetLocation() {
        return this.canGetLocation;
    }

    /**
     * Function to show settings alert dialog
     * On pressing Settings button will lauch Settings Options
     * */
    public void showSettingsAlert(){
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);

        // Setting Dialog Title
        alertDialog.setTitle("GPS is settings");

        // Setting Dialog Message
        alertDialog.setMessage("GPS is not enabled. Do you want to go to settings menu?");

        // On pressing Settings button
        alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Settings", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int which) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                mContext.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        // on pressing cancel button
       /* alertDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.cancel();
            }
        });*/

        // Showing Alert Message
        alertDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        return null;
    }

}
```

Comment: post your logcat then.

Comment: Which line is 163 in `AndroidGPSTrackingActivity.java`?

Comment: if(gps.getAccur()<=3.0D)

Answer (score 1):

Based on your Code. I found the Issues where its getting Crashed. Might be The Instance of your gps is null or is getting changed to null. Check this first

```
if(gps!=null){
  //your code
}else{
   Log.i("Your Classs Name::","GPS Object is null")
}
```

I sure you will get Log Message as GPS Object is null..

If still get Null then re-initialize the gps object.